# Blocked a frame with origin "domain1" from accessing a frame with origin "domain2"

Tags: javascript, http, browser

I am having problems while trying to make a page reload whenever the session expires on my website that is contained inside an iframe at a client's domain.

I know that browsers do not allow cross domain control for whatever security reasons, the thing is, I made my client add in every http response two tags like :

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin","domain2"
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST"

In theory,this should tell any browser NOT to block my request to reload the website, but it still keeps on happening.

Is the request being blocked even before domain1 says : ok, I will allow this domain to do whatever it wants to me?

Comment: i recommend postMessage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage to iframe interactions. This more crossbrowsing way

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

You need to use postMessage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage for interactions with iframes.